# How to include params in PowerShell call from cmd?

Tags: powershell

I've been trying to run Windows PowerShell scripts from a CMD with some parameters.

I've tried things like:

```
powershell -c ".\Test-Param.ps1 param1 param2"

powershell -c ".\Test-Param.ps1 -P1 param1 -P2 param2"

powershell -File ".\Test-Param.ps1 param1 param2"
```

This is the code I want to execute:

```
function Test-Param
{

    [CmdletBinding()] Param(
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $True)]
        [String]
        $P1,

        [Parameter(Position = 1, Mandatory = $True)]
        [String]
        $P2
    )
    echo "Script has been executed!!!"
    echo "Params: $P1,$P2\n"
}
```

I expect (P1="apple", P2="cherry"):

```
Script has been executed!!!
Params: apple,cherry
```

Comment: The code you posted is a function, but you're invoking a script. A function in a script will not magically invoke itself.

Answer (score 1):

You must put your parameters at the top of your script, not inside a function.

So your entire `.ps1` file should look like this:

```bsh
    [CmdletBinding()] Param(
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $True)]
        [String]
        $P1,

        [Parameter(Position = 1, Mandatory = $True)]
        [String]
        $P2
    )
    echo "Script has been executed!!!"
    echo "Params: $P1,$P2\n"
```